# HTML to landscape MS Word

Tags: html, ms-word, .doc

MS Word can interpret HTML as a document, but I want to specify in the HTML code to display it in landscaped letter pages. Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns:office="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
      xmlns:word="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<style>        
@page Section1 {size:595.45pt 841.7pt; margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in;mso-header-margin:.5in;mso-footer-margin:.5in;mso-paper-source:0;}
        div.Section1 {page:Section1;}
        @page Section2 {size:841.7pt 595.45pt;mso-page-orientation:landscape;margin:1.25in 1.0in 1.25in 1.0in;mso-header-margin:.5in;mso-footer-margin:.5in;mso-paper-source:0;}
        div.Section2 {page:Section2;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class=Section2>
<!--your content here-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML doesn't have the concept of "pages" and therefore also not of page orientation, you won't be able to achieve this with plain, out-of-the-box HTML. Word does have an HTML file format, but it is undocumented. It was added many years ago to enable round-tripping Word documents for display in a browser. If you save a Word document as a "Web Page" (NOT a filtered web page) then I think you get that file format (otherwise it's the "Single file web page" option). You can inspect that and try incorporating your HTML content into Word's HTML vocabulary.