# Data from SharePoint is being pulled into a HTML table and then its being exported to word, the table is not displaying fully

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have two links:

1) https://phppot.com/javascript/how-to-export-html-to-word-document-with-javascript/

2) [HTML to landscape MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872974/html-to-landscape-ms-word)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9yIo.png)

I am pulling SharePoint list data into a html table

Below is the code, but I'm not able to open the word in landscape mode or the table is not displaying properly.

```html
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <head>
      <title>How to Export HTML to Word Document with JavaScript</title>
      <style>
        #btn-export {
          background: #484848;
          color: #FFF;
          border: #000 1px solid;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          font-size: 12px;
          border-radius: 3px;
        }
    
        .content-footer {
          text-align: center;
        }
    
        .source-html-outer1 {
          border: #d0d0d0 1px solid;
          border-radius: 3px;
          padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
        }
    
        .Section2 td,
        .Section2 th {
          border: 1px solid;
        }
    
        @page source-html-outer {
          size: 841.7pt 595.45pt;
          mso-page-orientation: landscape;
          margin: 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in 1.0in;
          mso-header-margin: .5in;
          mso-footer-margin: .5in;
          mso-paper-source: 0;
        }
    
        div.source-html-outer {
          @page: source-html-outer;
        }
    
        @page Section2 {size:841.7pt 595.45pt;mso-page-orientation:landscape;margin:1.25in 1.0in 1.25in 1.0in;mso-header-margin:.5in;mso-footer-margin:.5in;mso-paper-source:0;}
            div.Section2 {@page:Section2;}
      </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class="Section2">
        <div id="source-html-outer" class="source-html-outer">
    
          <table style="border:1px solid black ; display: table-caption;" class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Requirement Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Document Description</th>
                <th scope="col">Documentation Link</th>
                <th scope="col">Evidence Gap</th>
                <th scope="col">Evidence Gap Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Evidence Gap Status Update</th>
    
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbodyawards">
    
            </tbody>
    
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-footer">
        <button id="btn-export" type="button" onclick="return exportHTML();">Export to word
          doc</button>
      </div>
    
      <script>
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
          if (!url) url = window.location.href;
          name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
          var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
          if (!results) return null;
          if (!results[2]) return '';
          return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
          var id = getParameterByName("ID");
          getMyListData(id);
        })
    
        function getMyListData(id) {
          var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Evidence-Gap')/items?$select=*,ParentRequirement/Id," +
            "ParentRequirement/Title&$expand=ParentRequirement&$filter=ParentRequirement/Id eq " + id
          $.ajax({
            url: url
            ,
            method: "GET", headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", }, success: function (data) {
              var
                restResults = data.d.results; for (var i = 0; i < restResults.length; i++) {
                  $('#tbodyawards').append('<tr><td width="30px">' + restResults[i].ParentRequirement.Title + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width:auto">' + restResults[i].Title + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width:auto"><a href="' + restResults[i].Documentationlink.Url + '">' + restResults[i].Documentationlink.Description + '</a></td>' +
                    '<td style="width:auto">' + restResults[i].EvidenceGap0 + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width:auto">' + restResults[i].EvidenceGap + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width:40px">' + restResults[i].EvidenceGapStatusUpdate + '</td></tr>');
    
                }
    
    
            },
            error: function (sender, args) {
              console.log('test');
            }
          });
        };
    
    
    
        function exportHTML() {
          var header = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " +
            "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' " +
            "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" +
            "<head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML to Word Document with JavaScript</title>" +
            "<style>        @page Section2 {size:841.7pt 595.45pt;mso-page-orientation:landscape;margin:1.25in 1.0in 1.25in 1.0in;mso-header-margin:.5in;mso-footer-margin:.5in;mso-paper-source:0;}" +
              "div.Section2 {page:Section2;}"+
            "</style>" +
            "</head><body>";
          var footer = "</body></html>";
          var sourceHTML = header + document.getElementById("source-html-outer").innerHTML + footer;
    
          var source = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(sourceHTML);
          var fileDownload = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(fileDownload);
          fileDownload.href = source;
          fileDownload.download = 'document.doc';
          fileDownload.click();
          document.body.removeChild(fileDownload);
          return false;
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as below.

```
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <head>
      <title>How to Export HTML to Word Document with JavaScript</title>
      <style>
        #btn-export {
          background: #484848;
          color: #FFF;
          border: #000 1px solid;
          padding: 10px 20px;
          font-size: 12px;
          border-radius: 3px;
        }

        .content-footer {
          text-align: center;
        }

        .source-html-outer1 {
          border: #d0d0d0 1px solid;
          border-radius: 3px;
          padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
        }

        .Section2 td,
        .Section2 th {
          border: 1px solid;
        }

        @page source-html-outer {
          size: 841.7pt 595.45pt;
          mso-page-orientation: landscape;
          margin: 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in 1.0in;
          mso-header-margin: .5in;
          mso-footer-margin: .5in;
          mso-paper-source: 0;

        }

        div.source-html-outer {
          @page: source-html-outer;
        }      
      }
        @page Section2 {size:841.7pt 595.45pt;mso-page-orientation:landscape;margin:1.25in 1.0in 1.25in 1.0in;mso-header-margin:.5in;mso-footer-margin:.5in;mso-paper-source:0;}
            div.Section2 {@page:Section2;}
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="Section2">
        <div id="source-html-outer" class="source-html-outer" style="width:800px;">

          <table style="border:1px solid black ; display: table-caption; table-layout: fixed;" class="table" >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Requirement Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Document Description</th>
                <th scope="col">Documentation Link</th>
                <th scope="col">Evidence Gap</th>
                <th scope="col">Evidence Gap Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Evidence Gap Status Update</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbodyawards">

            </tbody>

          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-footer">
        <button id="btn-export" type="button" onclick="return exportHTML();">Export to word
          doc</button>
      </div>

      <script>
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
          if (!url) url = window.location.href;
          name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
          var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
          if (!results) return null;
          if (!results[2]) return '';
          return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
          var id = getParameterByName("ID");
          getMyListData(id);
        })

        function getMyListData(id) {
          var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Evidence-Gap')/items?$select=*,ParentRequirement/Id," +
            "ParentRequirement/Title&$expand=ParentRequirement&$filter=ParentRequirement/Id eq " + id
          $.ajax({
            url: url
            ,
            method: "GET", headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", }, success: function (data) {
              var
                restResults = data.d.results; for (var i = 0; i < restResults.length; i++) {
                  $('#tbodyawards').append('<tr><td width="30px">' + restResults[i].ParentRequirement.Title + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width:auto">' + restResults[i].Title + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width:auto"><a href="' + restResults[i].Documentationlink.Url + '">' + restResults[i].Documentationlink.Description + '</a></td>' +
                    '<td style="width:auto">' + restResults[i].EvidenceGap0 + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width:auto">' + restResults[i].EvidenceGap + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width:40px;word-break: break-all;">' + restResults[i].EvidenceGapStatusUpdate + '</td></tr>');    
                }   
            },
            error: function (sender, args) {
              console.log('test');
            }
          });
        };



        function exportHTML() {
          var header = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' " +
            "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' " +
            "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>" +
            "<head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML to Word Document with JavaScript</title>" +
            "<style>        @page Section2 {size:841.7pt 595.45pt;mso-page-orientation:landscape;margin:1.25in 1.0in 1.25in 1.0in;mso-header-margin:.5in;mso-footer-margin:.5in;mso-paper-source:0;}" +
              "div.Section2 {page:Section2;}"+
            "</style>" +
            "</head><body>";
          var footer = "</body></html>";
          var sourceHTML = header + document.getElementById("source-html-outer").innerHTML + footer;

          var source = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(sourceHTML);
          var fileDownload = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(fileDownload);
          fileDownload.href = source;
          fileDownload.download = 'document.doc';
          fileDownload.click();
          document.body.removeChild(fileDownload);
          return false;
        }
      </script>
    </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it worked but i did some modifications to open in landscape mode rather than changing the width. @LZ_MSFT.  I used different function but same css

Comment: function export_to_word() {  var link, blob, url;
      blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', document.getElementById("section").innerHTML], {
        type: 'application/msword'
      });
      url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link = document.createElement('A');
      link.href = url;
      link.download = 'Document';  // default name without extension 
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'Document.docx'); // IE10-11
      else link.click();  // other browsers
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    };

Comment: But can we embed document as attachments in the table and export to word document and those attachments should be objects in the word document so that people can download is that possible @LZ_MSFT ? please let me know